# @font-face not working in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face, webfonts

I have this CSS:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Bebas';
    src: url('Fonts/BebasNeue.eot');
    src: url('Fonts/BebasNeue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         /*url('bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),*/
         url('Fonts/BebasNeue.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Fonts/BebasNeue.svg#') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And I apply it in several divs throughout the page.  It works fine in every browser except IE.  I have a .eot file and the directory is correct.  For some reason, it just doesn't work.

Comment: As a first step I would suggest checking whether the browser actually tried to load the font, and whether it succeeded (using Fidddler, and/or "developer tools").  That will at least give more info on where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the font through [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and trying the example in IE?